# InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Encountering this error after upgrading from .NET Core 1.1

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Project1.Models.ApplicationUser]'
>   from root provider.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(RequestDelegate
>   next) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connstring")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o => {
                // configure identity options
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            })


  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
            app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
             .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

ApplicationDBContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options) {
        }


        public DbSet<UserDevice> UserDevices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<UserDevice>().HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.DeviceId }); // configure composite key
        }


    }
```

Comment: how did you upgrade? upgraded packages or moved code to a new project?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I updated the packages

Comment: Then you may either have forgotten to update something or something needs `IdentityOptions` options to initialize. try using `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>`

Comment: Fixed using                           
.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my application from .NET Core 1.x to 2.x and there is a very [detailed documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on how to migration from .NET Core 1.x to 2.x. You need to follow the instructions and make sure you do every step applicable to your project.

For example, I can tell your `Program.cs` is different from the one created by 2.X template.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>

        // You don't need .UseKestrel() and others as they're from 1.X.
        // .CreateDefaultBuilder() already includes them.

        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Since you haven't posted the code for `ApplicationUser`, I can only post mine. Since I need to change the primary key from the default string to GUID, I need to create custom classes for application user and roles.

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName => $"{ this.FirstName } { this.LastName }";
}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
}
```

Then you need to inherit from the IdentityDbContext of AppUser, AppRole and the GUID primary key.

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<AppRole>().ToTable("Role");

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>().ToTable("UserRole");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>().ToTable("RoleClaim");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>().ToTable("UserToken");
    }
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices` call, you're missing `.AddEntityFrameworkStores()` and `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()`.

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(o => {
    // configure identity options
    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
// Components that generate the confirm email and reset password tokens
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```